# PostgreSQL - triggers to fire only on replicated db

Tags: postgresql, trigger

Is it possible to fire triggers only on a read-only Postgres replicated database?

I want triggers to fire only on the replicated database - not on the master (to avoid load). This is to track - say - all updates/deletes.

Would enabling replica trigger be the way to go?
On the primary/master, the triggers remain disabled, but in the replicated db, we can have the triggers fired?

The wal2json plugin is an option, but triggers seem a safer bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with logical replication, but not with streaming (physical) replication, because in the latter case the standby server is read-only.

For logical replication, you have to define the trigger as replica trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tgname ... ON TABLE atable ...;
ALTER atable ENABLE REPLICA TRIGGER tgname;
```

Comment: if there is a streaming replication already set from master, can logical replication be enabled on the same? can logical replication be enabled on a async replica instead of the master ?

Comment: Yes to the first question, no to the second.

Comment: wouldnt adding logical replication to the master add more load to it ? It is better off then having the triggers in the master itself?

Comment: Logical replication is **way** cheaper than a trigger.